# symfony 2.8 debug fatal error double message

Tags: symfony, debugging, components, fatal-error

Environment: Symfony 2.8.1 with XAMPP Version 5.5.24 on Windows 7.

If I trigger a fatal error in a controller, anything as simple as `$array = ;` in production environment, I'm getting a default php error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tgsupport-test\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 16

followed by symfony custom error page message. Obviously I'd want to avoid to show eorr info in production.
Moreover in prod.log I see a double critical error: under php.CRITICAL and request.CRITICAL. Is really useful to show the same error twice?

I'm using default configuration, indeed I just installed default framework without any custom setting and I triggered my error in AppBundle/DefaultController, so I was wondering if I'm missing anything.

Comment: this is probably a bug which will be fixed in 2.8.2. see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16980

Comment: to avoid displaying error messages in production mode you can easily use custom error pages as described in http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: even if I use a custom error page, I can only intercept symfony built error message, not default php error message which is displayed ABOVE <html> tag in error page

Answer (score 0):

I missed a php.ini configuration to avoid to display error messages in page.